# UIPickerView pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView: does not affect below iOS 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

My UIPickerView retrieves it's data using the `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` method.

For some reason the method doesn't affect on iOS 4.3 and below.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{   
    UILabel* label = (UILabel*)view;

    if (view == nil) {
        label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    }

    label.text = @"Text";

    return label;
}
```

Comment: do any of the other UIPickerViewDelegate methods work on pre iOS 4.3 devices for you?  how do you set your delegate and did you put the protocol declaration in your .h "`@interface`" file?

Comment: All the other delegate methods work on pre iOS 5.0 device.
UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy has made an example where he states that the view should not be autoreleased. http://alisothegeek.com/2009/07/custom-uipickerview-text-formatting/

Comment: Could the problem then be that you initialize the label with CGRectZero?